# How do i change screen through the function?

Tags: python, kivymd

I have an app but how do i change screen not through the kv, but through the python function,
There is my python code and i get an error name 'root' is not defined. Tried to do the same thing but with self and it said that MainApp has no attribute screen_manager, so how do i access it?

```
class Main(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("Main.kv")
    def on_start(self):
        if is_logged():
            self.screen_manager.current="main_screen"
        else:
            self.screen_manager.current="login_screen"

    def is_logged():
        return False

MainApp().run()
```

also here is my kv code

```
<LoginScreen>:
    id: login_screen
    text: "Login"
    icon: "login"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text:"Welcome to Plaim"
            font_style:"H4"
            text_color:"0,0,0,1"          
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"login"
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"password"
            id: password
            password: True
            hint_text: "Password"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Sign In"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("main_screen")
<Main>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: main
    ScreenManager:
        LoginScreen:
            name: "login_screen"
            id: login_screen
        MainScreen:
            name: "main_screen"
            id: main_screen
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code with all imports.

Comment: if `is_logged()` is part of class `MainApp()` then you need `self` - `def is_logged(self):` and `if self.is_logged()`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful informatin.

Comment: I tried to run your code and in some moments worked for me `self.root.current`

Comment: or `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current` but it needs `ScreenManager: id: screen_manager`  in `kv` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created minimal working code and I needed

```
self.root.current = "main_screen"
```

or

```
self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "main_screen"
```

---

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen #, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class Main(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
    
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
    
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("Main.kv")
        
    def on_start(self):
        #print(type(self))
        #print(type(self.root))
        #print(type(self.root.ids))
        #print(type(self.root.ids.screen_manager))

        if is_logged():
            self.root.current = "main_screen"
            #self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "main_screen"
        else:
            self.root.current = "login_screen"
            #self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "login_screen"

def is_logged():
    return True

MainApp().run()
```

**Main.kv**

```
Main:
    id: main
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text: "Hello World"
        
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        name: "screen_manager"
        
        LoginScreen:
        MainScreen:

<LoginScreen>:
    id: login_screen
    name: "login_screen"
    
    text: "Login"
    icon: "login"
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text:"Welcome to Plaim"
            font_style:"H4"
            text_color:"0,0,0,1"          
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"login"
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"password"
            id: password
            password: True
            hint_text: "Password"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Sign In"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "main_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
<MainScreen>:
    id: main_screen
    name: "main_screen"
    
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "LOGIN"
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "login_screen"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

---

**BTW:**

If I use lower case name `main.kv` then I don't need

```
 return Builder.load_file("Main.kv")
```

but I can use

```
 return Main()
```

and it loads `main.kv` automatically.

But in `main.kv` I have to use `<Main>:` instead of `Main:`

---

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen #, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class Main(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
    
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
    
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Main()
        
    def on_start(self):
        #print(type(self))
        #print(type(self.root))
        #print(type(self.root.ids))
        #print(type(self.root.ids.screen_manager))

        if is_logged():
            self.root.current = "main_screen"
            #self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "main_screen"
        else:
            self.root.current = "login_screen"
            #self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "login_screen"

def is_logged():
    return True

MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv** (lower case name)

```
<Main>:
    id: main
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text: "Hello World"
        
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        name: "screen_manager"
        
        LoginScreen:
        MainScreen:

<LoginScreen>:
    id: login_screen
    name: "login_screen"
    
    text: "Login"
    icon: "login"
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text:"Welcome to Plaim"
            font_style:"H4"
            text_color:"0,0,0,1"          
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"login"
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"password"
            id: password
            password: True
            hint_text: "Password"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Sign In"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "main_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
<MainScreen>:
    id: main_screen
    name: "main_screen"
    
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "LOGIN"
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "login_screen"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```